# Tower defence direction change

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to do a simple tower defence game. 
My tanks are moving along the road. How can I tell them to stop at X / Y axis and rotate and move to a different direction?

```
function panzer(){
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 230;
    this.xSpeed = 5;
    this.display = function(){ //function to display tank

        playArea.context.drawImage(panzerImg,this.x,this.y,400,270);
    }
    this.move = function(){ //function to move

        //while(this.x != 1800){ Commented concept to move while x(axis) != 1800
            this.x += this.xSpeed;
            if((this.x+20)<0) this.x = playArea.canvas.width;
       // }

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to add a condition to your `.move` method to check for the `x` and `y` properties of each tank against your turning point coords `x` and `y`

Comment: Could you please tell me how? Because I am running late with this school project and I didn't find anything on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like

```
if(this.x==POSITION && this.y==POSITION){
    ROTATE
}
```

On the `if()` part, that means when the tank's X and Y position is at where you want it to stop and rotate, then ROTATE.
The way you rotate is change the tank's X and Y speed. If you wanna do more, then make another picture of tank at different direction, then `drawImage`.